# Running Jfrog cli in different docker container and using that cli in the Gitlab CI/CD pipeline

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, jfrog-cli

I'm running my CI/CD pipeline in Gitlab and I'm using the Jfrog cli to scan my code. The issue is that I'm downloading the cli every time that I'm running the CI/CD pipeline. I want to have that cli in a docker image that I can use every time that I need to run the pipeline in my Gitlab server. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [installation instructions](https://jfrog.com/getcli/), 
you can run JFrog CLI in a docker image:

```
docker run docker.bintray.io/jfrog/jfrog-cli-go:latest jfrog -v
```

Or you can build your own Docker image with the JFrog CLI installed. Here a couple of links for that:

- https://www.scalyr.com/blog/create-docker-image/ (explains how to use `docker commit` which is how you can create an image from a running container)
- https://stackify.com/docker-build-a-beginners-guide-to-building-docker-images/
- https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/

Comment: Aleksey, thanks for your answer, it was pretty useful. But I'm still having a situation that I don't know how to resolve. I need then in my CI/CD pipeline in Gitlab use that installation of the Jfrog CLI, now I'm downloading the CLI every time that I'm executing the pipeline.

Comment: Okay. Why don't you build your own Docker image with the JFrog CLI installed, and use that image?